# How to ignore everyone and here in message.mentions.has("")?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on("message", message => { if (message.mentions.has("665761320284053538"))
...so on.
```

The following gets triggered when @here or #everyone are mentioned. How can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Check for the id && the mention isnt `@here` or `@everyone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.on("message", message => { if (!message.mentions.has(message.mentions.EVERYONE_PATTERN) && message.mentions.has("665761320284053538"))
.
.
.
```

[.EVERYONE_PATTERN](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-EVERYONE_PATTERN) means `@everyone` and `@here`.

There is also `.ROLES_PATTERN`, `.USERS_PATTERN` and `.CHANNELS_PATTERN`. They're static [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) type.